# How to call object function after click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how to make this code work: http://jsfiddle.net/LBXVd/2/. It's almost clean jqueryboilerplate, I'm interested in this part of code:

```
Plugin.prototype = {

    init: function() {

        /// create element <a> with click function
        myEl = $('<a/>', {  
            href: '#',
            text: '###',
           click: function(e){this._handler();}
    });
     $('ul').before(myEl);
    },


    //handler for click events on my <a> element...
    _handler: function(el, options) {
        alert("my handler called");
    }
};
```

How can I call function _handler after click on created  element?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your jsfiddle isn't very helpful since it doesn't show any result ... however I think it's because `this` in the `this._handler()` call is not what you think (it is the `<a>` element and not the prototype object).

Try

```
init: function() {

    var self = this; // ****

    /// create element <a> with click function
    myEl = $('<a/>', {  
        href: '#',
        text: '###',
       click: function(e){self._handler();} // ****
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I fixed my jsfiddle and tried your code. It works!